# Why javax.net files are not available in src.zip?

Tags: java, java-8

I installed `1.8.0_162-b12` in my local. When trying to see the source of the java core files in my eclipse, I don't see the source of classes under `javax.net`.

On unzipping my `src.zip` I see there are no files named `net` under `javax`, which means the source for `javax.net.*` are not part of `src.zip`.

Why are those not part of `src.zip`?

Answer (score 2):

As per open JDK issue tracker

> What's in javax.net is part of the Security Code (JSSE) therefore, the
>   sources are not available through normal means for export control
>   reasons.

For more info visit the [link](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4811569)

Answer (score 2):

In January 2024, the AdoptOpenJDK version of the javax.net code appears to be here:
https://github.com/adoptium/jdk/tree/master/src/java.base/share/classes/javax/net

There is an old JDK8 archive here as well (archived on Sep 29, 2021):
https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk8u/tree/master/jdk/src/share/classes/javax/net/